# Do video cameras use the same image sensors as still cameras?

Tags: sensor, video

Do video cameras have the [image sensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor) cameras have?

I really don't know what I'm talking about, so if the answer was explained, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: While some questions about video cameras are on topic here, we try to have them answer this question "Can I use this information in still photography?", if they do not answer that, then they are probably off topic here. See the FAQ for more info http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: +1 to what dpollit says. Arguably, _this_ question has a the between-the-lines aspect of "so, if they are the same, can I use them in still photography?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes. Digital video cameras use these sensors**, usually CCDs but CMOS too. These are the same designs use for still cameras but with less pixels, since even HD footage only needs 2 MP. For HD cameras, the shape of the sensor is often different to match the 16:9 aspect of widescreen footage.

The major difference you will encounter are cameras labelled as *[3 CCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-CCD_camera)*. Again this is the same type of sensor but there are 3 of them, one for each of red, green and blue. Special prisms are used to divide incoming light and reflect it towards each sensor. On a conventional digital camera, colors are *almost* always divided between adjacent pixels using a [Bayer filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter). There are some Sigma cameras which use special Foveon sensors which capture different colors in layers instead.

Comment: +1 great answer.  I don't have edit privileges, so please change "One a conventional digital camera..." to "On a conventional...